# what is the difference between port-channel and etherchannel?

Tags: cisco, etherchannel, port-channel

As the title said, I do not make the difference between port-channel and etherchannel. For me they both aggregate ports in an Ethernet networks using Cisco parlance.
What subtlety do I miss ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"EtherChannel" or "Link Aggregation" is the particular technology that allows you to bundle several links between two devices and use them simultaneously as a single interface.

"Port-channel" is the name of this virtual interface in IOS. This is similar to, say, WiFi as a technology, and "Dot11Radio0" as the name of the interface, or ISDN as a technology, and BRI as an interface name.

There can be similarities in the actual command used on Cisco IOS or Nexus NX-OS to show a summarized list of Port-channels, for instance, on IOS the command  is:

```
show etherchannel summary
```

Where on NX-OS, the command is:

```
show port-channel summary
```